# Is There A Way to Use Overrideable Behaviour in a Call to a Base Class Constructor?

Tags: c#, .net

The title is a bit abstract so maybe it is easier to explain with a specific example:

I find it useful to have my exception classes take an enum parameter instead of a string message.

```
throw new SpecificException(SpecificExceptionCode.ThisThingWentWrong);
```

There are few reasons for this, including:

- I can encapulate all the logic for accessing localized string resources in one place
- I can easily make sure I have string resources for all my exception messages
- Checking for correct exception messages in unit tests is simpler

I would like to write a base class for this type of exception. Derived exception classes generally just want to provide their own System.Resources.ResourceManager but may also provide additional constructors. The trouble comes because I can only call static methods in calls to base class constructors. This leads me to something like:

```
public abstract class BaseException : ApplicationException
{
    protected static ResourceManager m_resources;
    public BaseException(System.Enum errorCode, params object[] messageArgs) 
        : base(ProcessError(errorCode, messageArgs))
    {}

    private static string ProcessError(Enum errorCode, params object[] messageArgs)
    {
        string errorMessage = m_resources.GetString(errorCode.ToString());
        // Handling of messageArgs and trace logging
        // ....
        return finalError;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SpecificException : BaseException
{
    static SpecificException()
    {
        m_resources = //.. Get an appropriate resource manager instance
    }

    public SpecificException(SpecificExceptionCode errorCode, params object[] messageArgs)
        : base(errorCode, messageArgs)
    {}
}
```

This works, but I am unhappy with it as there is no compile time hint that the derived class must provide its own `System.ResourceManager`. I would like to have a base class such as:

```
public abstract class BaseException : ApplicationException
{
    protected abstract static ResourceManager Resources{get;}

    public BaseException(System.Enum errorCode, params object[] messageArgs) 
        : base(ProcessError(errorCode, messageArgs))
    {}

    private static string ProcessError(Enum errorCode, params object[] messageArgs)
    {
        string errorMessage = Resources.GetString(errorCode.ToString());
        // Handling of messageArgs and trace logging
        // ....
        return finalError;
    }
}
```

...but I cannot have an abstract static method. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Your current code is broken... there is only one static field; the last static ctor to execute wins.

Re using a non-static method - note that calling virtual/abstract methods in a constructor is a bit dangerous - the concrete class won't have initialized yet, so the override could attempt to use data that isn't yet available.

Can ResourceManager not be an argument to the base-constructor? If they pass null, you use a sensible default...
ProcessError would then accept a ResourceManager, etc.

```
public abstract class BaseException : ApplicationException
{
    static ResourceManager defaultManager;
    static ResourceManager DefaultManager
    {
        get
        {
            if (defaultManager == null) defaultManager = TODO; // sensible default
            return defaultManager;
        }
    }

    public BaseException(System.Enum errorCode, params object[] messageArgs)
        : this(DefaultManager, errorCode, messageArgs) {}
    public BaseException(ResourceManager resourceManager, System.Enum errorCode, params object[] messageArgs)
        : base(ProcessError(resourceManager, errorCode, messageArgs))
    { }

    private static string ProcessError(ResourceManager resourceManager, Enum errorCode, params object[] messageArgs)
    {
        if (resourceManager == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("resourceManager");
        string errorMessage = resourceManager.GetString(errorCode.ToString());
        // Handling of messageArgs and trace logging
        // ....
        return finalString;
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class SpecificException : BaseException
{
    static ResourceManager customManager;
    static SpecificException()
    {
        customManager = //TODO - init manager
    }
    public SpecificException(SomeEnum errorCode, params object[] messageArgs)
        : base(customManager, errorCode, messageArgs)
    { }
}
```

Classes that don't want to provide their own manager just use the other ctor:

```
: base(errorCode, messageArgs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be a static property? You can make the Resources normal property:

```
protected abstract static ResourceManager Resources{get;}
```

and just leave it for the implementer to implement it to return a static object:

```
private static ResourceManager resources = ....

protected override static ResourceManager Resources{get {return resources; }}
```

Comment: It would be nice to have override and static members! :)))

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a protected constructor that takes a resource manager as a parameter?  That way your concrete exception would have to pass it in.

I would tend to use a factory method rather than the constructor for this kind of issue though.

```
public static SpecificException SpecificExceptionCodeName()
{
    //Do resource lookup and create Exception
}
```

and then use

```
throw ExceptionBuilder.SpecificExceptionCodeName();
```

this way you get the  benefits you outlined without having to inherit from a specific base exception which allows you to throw any Exception you like.  There are several places in the framework where it is internally using this method.  Note that I tend not to put the factory method on the concrete exception because they showup on derived classes which can get.